# remove life from stage after mouseclick as3 code is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have added 5 life icons on a container in stage..now i want to remove them one by one by mouse click.it is working for first click(one child is removing from stage).but it is not working after that.what should i do.there is no error in code but not working.here is the code

```
var Lives:Number = 5;
var Spacing:Number = 5;
var nextX:Number = 0;

for(var i:int = 0; i < Lives; i++ )
{
var mc:MovieClip = new mcPlayerLives();
mc.x = nextX;
lives_container.addChild(mc );

nextX += mc.width + Spacing;
}

attackButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeLife);
function removeLife(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
   // Lives= Lives - 1;
      if (lives_container.contains(mc))
         lives_container.removeChild(mc);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the variable `mc` in the loop. When loop end, `mc` point to the last instance of the `mcPlayerLives` class. In the `removeLife` function you remove only last instance of the `mcPlayerLives` class.

Instead of

```
if (lives_container.contains(mc))
     lives_container.removeChild(mc);
```

use

```
if (lives_container.numChildren)
     lives_container.removeChildAt(0);
```

It means: if `lives_container` contains at least one child, remove the child.